# vscode cannot go to file when cmd + click (@import "~path/for/index.less") in a less file

Tags: visual-studio-code, less, less-loader

I am importing a less file and the url starting with "~",

```
//in custom.less
@import "~iview/src/styles/index.less";
```

I want to go to the file by cmd + click the url, but i got an error saying:

```
Unable to open 'index.less': File not found 
(file:///Users/jameslam/Sites/Playground/my-first-iview/src/~iview/src/styles/index.less).
```

It seems that vscode cannot understand "~" in the url, which stands for `./node_modules/`
How can i set the configuration to make vscode support that.

### Expectation:

When click the url, open index.less (file:///Users/jameslam/Sites/Playground/my-first-iview/node_modules/iview/src/styles/index.less)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860667/836330 as of v1.57.