# vscode "Intellisense" and "Go to definition" for not js/ts files

Tags: javascript, frontend, visual-studio-code

In frontend-development we often import not only javascript/typescript files in javasctipt.  We import such files using both aliases an relative paths.

Example:

```
import brandsQuery from '~/graphql/queries/brands.gql';
import Button from '~/components/common/button/index.vue';
import Component from './list/index.vue';
```

By default VS Code doesn't support not js/ts extensions when we import such files - there are no "Intellisense" and "Go to Definitoon" for such files.

I tried such extensions: [Path intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) and [Path autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete)

VS Code settings to support alias:

```
  "path-intellisense.mappings": {
    "~/": "${workspaceFolder}",
  },
```

or

```
  "path-autocomplete.pathMappings": {
    "~/": "${folder}/",
  }
```

With these extensions we have autocomplete when we write import string. Also for relative paths "Go To Definition" works.

But "Go To Definition" doesn't work for not js-ts files imported using alias.

Do you know some way to have both "Intellisense", "Go To Definition" for all extensions that I need in my project?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860603/836330 as of v1.57 due next week.

Comment: I too am having this issue in March of 2023. I have aliases setup and go to definition will not work on .css files utilizing the alias in the import path. If I change to relative go to definition works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_57.md#go-to-definition-for-non-jsts-files

> Many modern JS bundlers and frameworks use `import` statements to
> import assets such as images and stylesheets. We now support
> navigating through these imports with `go to definition`:

[image: go to definition for imports]

> This is probably most useful when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>
> click to navigate through your code.